# While infinite loop

Tags: java

I get an infinite loop in this code

I'm just trying to get the user to reenter the integer just once in the while loop

Where is the problem?

```
System.out.print ("Enter a number: ");

while (!scan.hasNextInt())
  System.out.print ("reenter as integer: ");
  num = scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: You're missing some curly braces (`{}`) to form the block.

Comment: So it checks if scan has a Next Int, it doesn't so it asks you for an int. The int gets used up and it checks again and doesn't have an int. It asks you for an int and . . . you see where this is going?

Comment: You have incorrect formatting.  Use the formatter in your IDE and the problem would be obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Scanner#hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) method doesn't move the cursor past any input. So, it will keep on testing against the same input which you give and hence will keep on failing if it fails once. So, if you input `"abc"`, then `hasNextInt()` will keep on testing against `"abc"`, and thus will go into an infinite loop.

You need to use [`Scanner#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) method inside the while loop for that.

Also, you should consider using some maximum attempt for user to enter correct input, so that this doesn't go into infinite loop if user keeps on passing invalid input.

```
int maxTries = 3;
int count = 0;

while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
    if (++count == maxTries) {
        // Maximum Attempt reached.
        // throw some exception
    }

    System.out.print ("reenter as integer: ");        
    scan.next();  // Move cursor past current input
}

num = scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: Just so you have visibility over the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Your while loop isn't actually consuming what it sees. You need to consume the non-integer input:

```
while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.print ("reenter as integer: ");
    scan.next(); // Consumes the scanner input indiscriminately (to a delimiter)
}

num = scan.nextInt(); // Consumes the scanner input as an int
```

Comment: No. This won't solve the issue. In fact, you are trying to read an integer, when the `hasNextInt` method says there is no int to read.

Comment: @RohitJain Have you tried that code? This works for me: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6642254

Comment: @OscarRyz. Don't know how that works for you. It can never work. Try giving an input - `"abc"`, this will throw exception at `nextInt()` method.

Comment: @RohitJain Gah, I forgot the try catch. Fixing it now.

Comment: @RohitJain I see what you mean. It solved the infinite loop though

Comment: @OscarRyz Of course it solved that. But what's the point. It added another issue.

Comment: @RohitJain the point is to understand what is causing the infinite loop, have the op asked how to read an integer from the console that's another thing. Anyway, here's the correct anwser

Comment: @OscarRyz Yes, I know. Anyway, I went after the first thing I saw and didn't test my answer before posting.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Gah, I meant indiscriminate in the sense it wouldn't try to parse it as an int or long or any such thing. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

The expression "!scan.hasNextInt()" translates to "there is not another int for which I can scan"  Consider looping on "scan.hasNextInt()" which translates to "there is another int for which I can scan"

Answer (score 0):

You don't have braces so the while loop cycles through the System.out.print statement and never exists.

If you add the braces as  it is you will fail at reading an int when a non/integer is entered.

To properly read an integer you have to loop *asking* for the next token, and then verifying it was an int.

```
$cat Wt.java
import java.util.*;

class Wt {
    public static void main( String ... args ) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Write a number: ");
        while ( !s.hasNextInt()) {
             System.out.print("Write a number: ");
             s.next(); // <-- ask for the next and see if that was an int
        }
        int n = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The number was: " + n );
    }
}

$javac Wt.java
$java Wt
Write a number: one
Write a number: two
Write a number: tres
Write a number: 1.1
Write a number: f
Write a number: 42
The number was: 42
```